# Using variables in to use Validation in Excel VBA: use variable to define Operator

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a reference table to hold variables to define Date validations. I've used similar code to define List validations from a reference table w/o issues. It appears that I have an issue with assigning a value to OPERATOR using a table-driven value. Any assistance appreciated.

```
For Each c In dateFields
              fieldName = "entry_" & c.Value
              validateOperator = "xl" & dropDownSh.Cells(c.Row, c.Column + 1).Value 'list of operator values, e.g., "Between", etc.
              validateStart = dropDownSh.Cells(c.Row, c.Column + 2).Value
              validateStop = dropDownSh.Cells(c.Row, c.Column + 3).Value
              If validateStop = "" Then validateStop = validateStart
              MsgBox (fieldName & ":" & validateList)

              Range(fieldName).Select
              With Selection.Validation
                    .Delete
                    If validateOperator = "xlBetween" Then
                          .Add Type:=xlValidateDate, _
                          AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                          Operator:=validateOperator, _
                          Formula1:=validateStart, _
                          Formula2:=validateStop
                    Else
                          .Add Type:=xlValidateDate, _
                          AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                          Operator:=xlGreaterEqual, _
                          Formula1:=validateStart
                    End If

                    .IgnoreBlank = True
                    .InCellDropdown = True
                    .InputTitle = ""
                    .ErrorTitle = ""
                    .InputMessage = ""
                    .ErrorMessage = ""
                    .ShowInput = True
                    .ShowError = True
              End With
        Next c
```

Comment: so where does your problem occur? step through the code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this:

```
validateOperator = "xl" & dropDownSh.Cells(c.Row, c.Column + 1).Value
```

and then use `validateOperator` as though it's an actual constant:

```
'....
If validateOperator = "xlBetween" Then
    .Add Type:=xlValidateDate, _
    AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=validateOperator, _
    Formula1:=validateStart, _
    Formula2:=validateStop
Else
'....
```

You need to pass the appropriate *value* (eg. `xlBetween` is 1, which you can find via the Object Browser in the VB editor) or the *actual constant*, not a string representing the name of the constant... You can use a table or a function to map your strings to their equivalent constant values.

Comment: Thanks! I will do as you suggested.